# Reading a file with root privilage and save it with another user or group

Tags: debian, root

I am going to read a file which needs root privilege and I have to save it somewhere with another user or group, for example reading dmesg which needs root and save it some other place with permission 770 for user/group: test/test. the problem here that I can not save it as root, is SElinux policy which gives me error.So I need to change the process privilage while I am saving the file.

any suggestion?

Comment: Will your script be running as root?

Comment: @roaima, yes, ,It runs as root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is running as root. So there's nothing to stop you using `sudo` to run as any user. If you can't write a file as root but you can as this other user, that's one option:

```
target=/path/to/target/file
dmesg | sudo -u test tee "$target" >/dev/null
chmod 770 "$target"
```

If you prefer to use `su` instead of `sudo` you can use this variant

```
target=/path/to/target/file
dmesg | su test -c "tee '$target' >/dev/null'
chmod 770 "$target"
```

Comment: I wonder if `install` could be used too?

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't think so - `strace` shows the file being written and then the ownership applied

Comment: Good call. Thanks for looking into that.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me, the only change I give was to use su instead of sudo and give the complete address of all command. for example dmesg and su

Comment: @AhmadBanshee both `dmesg` and `su` are in the standard `/bin` directory so you shouldn't have needed to provide full paths. Have you perhaps changed the `$PATH` variable by mistake?

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you can do (as `root`):

```
zmodload zsh/system
umask 0
() {local EGID=123 EUID=456; sysopen -wu3 -m770 -o excl file}
```

To create and open the `file` as euid 456 and egid 123 with 0770 permissions.

```
$ ls -nd file
-rwxrwx--- 1 456 123 0 Sep  5 17:05 file
```

And then run: `dmesg >&3` to fill it up.

(note that the order is important, you can't change the egid once your euid is no longer 0).